# how to add lines over a column bar graph where the lines pass by the middle-top of the bars considering bars with position='dodge'?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics, geom-col

Here I provide an example of what I have tried:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1:12), each = 2),
                 b = c("yes", "no"),
                 c = sample(x = 1:200, size = 24))

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = b), position = 'dodge') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(a):max(a)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = a, y = c, group = b), stat = "identity")
```

So basically what I want to obtain is two bars for each xtick, with a line for each bar set passing by the top-center of each matching  bar. I would want these two lines to have colours corresponding to the bar set they match.

I have seen a question posted here for C language. It had some similarities to this question but it was not much of a help.

If anyone knows how to achieve this I would be thankful :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to set `position = position_dodge()` in both `geom_col` and `geom_line`.

If you set the line color as the same color as the bar, it's very hard to visualise the lines. Here I manually set "no" to "black" and "yes" to "firebrick" by `scale_color_manual`. Remove the code `scale_color_manual(values = c("no" = "black", "yes" = "firebrick"), name = "line")` to align the colors with the bars.

```r
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(a = rep(c(1:12), each = 2),
                 b = c("yes", "no"),
                 c = sample(x = 1:200, size = 24))

ggplot(df, aes(x = a, y = c, group = b, fill = b)) + 
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_line(aes(col = b), position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("no" = "black", "yes" = "firebrick"), name = "line")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your clearly solves the problem, but it comes with an additional inconvenient: I just want the "b" legend and not the "line" one. How would you do that?

Comment: @Miguel_s I deliberately separated the legends in my above answer. Remove `name = "line"` in the `scale_color_manual` to remove the line legend.

Comment: Sorry, I did not complete my answer. Here is what I wanted to say: in case I want to switch the title of the bars legend from "b" to "Data" for example, how should I proceed? I have tried adding | + labs(fill="Data") | to the code, though that brings back two legends.

Comment: @Miguel_s One hack around is to include `guide = "none"` in `scale_color_manual`, and set your `labs(fill = "Data")`. That is `scale_color_manual(values = c("no" = "black", "yes" = "firebrick"), guide = "none") + labs(fill = "Data")`

Comment: That trick just did it. Thank you @benson23 :)